# Android SQLite delete multiple rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete all rows in a table with a specific ID (not primary key).
I have tested two different methods, but they only remove the first row it finds with the specific ID:

```
db.delete(CalendarTable.TABLE_NAME, "repeat_group="+repeatGroup, null);
```

and

```
db.delete(CalendarTable.TABLE_NAME, "repeat_group=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(repeatGroup)});
```

None of these methods works, how can I remove ALL rows in a table with this specific ID?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Lol, the method above did work! It was just me the stupid one that called the my own method delete() instead of deleteRepeatGroup(), guess I'm too tired! 
Anyways, thank you guys for taking your time.

Comment: it should work ... are you using transaction ?

Comment: I dont think I'm using transaction, how can I be sure if I do?

Comment: I even tried: db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM calendar WHERE repeat_group="+repeatGroup, null);

Comment: It has nothing do with transaction. The solution can be you can a raw query as the first answer suggest.

Comment: I've tried a raw query too. Doesn't work, only deletes the first row =/

Comment: public boolean deleteRows(int[] ids) {
  StringBuilder WHERE = new StringBuilder();
  for(int id : ids) {
   WHERE.append("repeat_group=").append(id).append(" or ");
  }
  WHERE.delete(WHERE.length() - 3, WHERE.length());
  return db.delete(CalendarTable.TABLE_NAME, WHERE, null) > 0;
 }

Comment: Try above code if its working, make an answer and put here as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything else fails, you can try the following. Get all rows in the table with the ID you are trying to delete and save the rowID's in an array. Then iterate over the array and delete each row.

I hope this works as expected

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
String urQuery = "delete from tablename where Id in ("
    + Id + ")";
```

here Id may have all ids separated by comma ex. "id1,id2".